# my graph is repeating values and I suspect its because one of my variables is not in a list so how do I convert the `variable` into a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, bar-chart

When I read a text file into a `variable` and use that `variable` as a `parameter` in a `function`, I get a graph with repeated values. I suspect it is because `variable` in the code below is not a list and when I try to use the `list()` function or wrap `variable` in `[]` it is unsuccessful. The goal of the code below is to read a text file into a `variable`, use that `variable` as a parameter in the `function`, count the words in a column of a `dataframe` based on `search_words1` and output a horizontal bar chart of the count of the words. the words will be on the y axis and the count will be on the x axis. Alternatively, when I declare `search_words1 = ['Job Completed','delay in estimate upload', 'mitigation needed']`, instead of using the `variable` read in from the text file, the code works fine. My question is how do I change `search_words1 = variable` into a list to see if that works to resolve the issue and if it doesn't work what direction can I take to get the right output of the horizontal bar chart?

```
# read text into variable
with open('text2.txt') as f:
    variable=f.read()

# declarations
    
ser = df['Comments']
search_words1 = variable
l2 = []

# I want to count the words in df['Comments'] based on search_words1 variable and create dataframe

def count(search_words1):
    for i in search_words1:
        c = ser[(ser.str.contains(i,regex=False))].count()
        l2.append(c)
    return pd.DataFrame({'Comments':search_words1, 'Count':l2})

# Call function and sort

twords=count(search_words1).sort_values(by='Count',ascending=False)

# graph results

twords.plot(kind='barh',x='Comments',figsize=(5,5),fontsize=14, title ='2021 Comments Common words')
```

first image is the bad output. the second image is the desired output.
[image: bad output]

[image: desired output]

Edits:
when using `variable = f.read()`, the `variable` looks like `'Job Completed', 'delay in estimate upload', 'mitigation needed'`  when using the print function on it and it is of type `str`. Graph output is the first image with this method.

when using `variable = f.readlines()`, the `variable` looks like `["'Job Completed',\n", " 'delay in estimate upload',\n", " 'mitigation needed' "]` when using the print function on it and it is of type `list`. Also, with this method, the graph output is similar to second image but with no horizontal bars within the chart frame.

Comment: Have you tried `variable=f.readlines()` instead of `variable=f.read()`. This will return a list albeit with \n appended at the end of each line.

Comment: Can you show us what `variable` looks like? And what is `type(variable)`?

Comment: @PankajSaini I just tried `variable=f.readlines()`, and get a blank output graph. see my edits above.

Comment: @DerekO I have edited post to show what `variable=f.read()` and `variable=f.readlines()` looks like when printed out and what the types are.

Comment: @hector.h2913 so you need to remove the quotes, newline and commas. Try this `var2 = map(lambda x: x.replace("'", "").replace(",", "").strip(), variable)` and then pass `list(var2)` to your count function. variable is the return from f.readlines()